# lower equal with dot

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a way to write the symbol "lower or equal" with a dot directly after it? Just like \lessdot but with the horizontal line added. Would be awesome if someone can tell me. I didn't find it after a long search.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine}
\newcommand\ledot{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.5ex}{\lessdot}{-}{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}
\begin{document}
$a\ledot b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it across mathstyles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\ledot{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-.5\LMex}{\SavedStyle\lessdot}{\SavedStyle-}{U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}}
\begin{document}
$a\ledot b$

$\scriptstyle a\ledot b$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\ledot b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Comments from the OP indicate a desire to add a subscript to the symbol.  The above formulations have too much depth to make that work well directly, so here is an alternative in which the underset is `\smash`ed and the underset depth is adjusted a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\ledot{\mathrel{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{.8\LMex}{\SavedStyle\lessdot}{\smash{\SavedStyle-}}%
  {U}{c}{F}{F}{S}}}}}
\begin{document}
$a\ledot_{\!P} b$

$\scriptstyle a\ledot_{\!P} b$

$\scriptscriptstyle a\ledot_{\!P} b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think anyone could actually tell me how you get this symbol.

Comment: @Kegorus you are welcome.  Note you can change the value of `-.5\LMex` to adjust the amount of underset between `<` and `-`, if you prefer a narrower or wider gap.

Comment: This made it even better, thanks! And one more thing, would it be possible to add a "P" (for poset P) as index? Like \Ieq_P with dot?

Comment: @Kegorus Do you mean for the `P` to be below the symbol, or to the lower right?  Also, what is to prevent you from doing exactly what you suggest, namely `\ledot_P`?

Comment: I want it to the lower right. When I write a\ledot_P b the distance between the symbol and b is a bit big, because the P wants to have enough space to the right I guess. Not sure if there is a way to change that though, if not I would still use it, it still looks good and is what I need.

Comment: @Kegorus Please see **ADDENDUM**

Comment: That's great now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

There is also a specific symbol `\leqslantdot` with `MnSymbol` package, or `fdsymbol`.

[image]

**Edit**: We observe that the `\leqslantdot` with `MnSymbol` not changes the CM fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
$f(a,b)\leqslantdot g(b,a)$
\end{document}
```

---

While if you use `fdsymbol`, you have not an exact dot but it is similar to the square with a zoom and there is a change of the font of the rounded brackets (for example).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
$f(a,b)\leqslantdot g(b,a)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you too! I will use the horizontal line version though.

Comment: @Kegorus No problem :-) the choice is yours :-)

Comment: I'm suddenly reminded of the pigpen cipher.

Comment: @Kaz What is? I have not understood your comment.

Comment: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrario_pigpen

Comment: @campa Thank you especially to have the link in Italian language :-) very appreciated.

Comment: @Kaz I have understood now with the link of the user campa your comment. Regards.